# TAEF Datadriven c# application on windows phone

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, taef

I am writing an C# application to read XML using "data driven method" as described in TAEF documentation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439689(v=vs.85).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh439591(v=vs.85).aspx

I have VSTS dll loaded and also TE.Managed.dll loaded in my references and in TAEF we set this TestContext property so you can access the data through it.

public TestContext TestContext

{

get { return m_testContext; }

set { m_testContext = value; }

}

At runtime when I run the testcase on the phone, I am getting this argument error

command - 
cmdd te.exe "c:\data\test\bin\UnitTestProject1.dll /select:@TestId='1004'"

Test Authoring and Execution Framework v4.16m for arm

***Error: System.ArgumentException: Object of type*** **'WEX.TestExecution.TestContextImplementation' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesti
ng.TestContext'.**

Removing all references to WEX.TestExecution is also giving me the same error. Could some one please help me with this !!!????

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try generating a unit test so the [TestContext is auto defined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404699(VS.80).aspx)? If not give that a go and look for any differences

Comment: I am still getting the same error. I used instructions from   - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182527.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the TestContext implementation in the Wex.TestExecution.Markup namespace in TE.Managed.dll when using the CoreCLR version of TE.Managed.dll. The CoreCLR version doesn't support the use of the TestContext class from Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTests.dll.